# Scraping website returns different values

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

Using this xpath

```
"/html/body/div[1]/table/tr[3]/td/table/tr[2]/td/div/div[2]"
```

returns 0 for mileage instead of the value shown on the website

http://www.mapdevelopers.com/mileage_calculator.php?&from=5894%20Dogwood%20Cir%2C%2035111&to=1515%20W%20Sanders%20St%2C%2036201

Why would I not retrieve the value shown on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **source HTML** has `<b>Driving mileage</b>: 0.0 miles, 0.0 kilometers (km)`.

The webpage is updated dynamically with JavaScript as the browser renders the page (you can see/verify more easily by disabling JavaScript in your browser).

Your scraper is not evaluating the JavaScript. It evaluates the XPath on the parsed source HTML.

Comment: How can the dynamic javascript be scraped?

Comment: @user974061, read the [mileage.js](http://www.mapdevelopers.com/js/mileage.js) script. One option is to implement the same behavior in another language and skip the scraping, or use [webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) to control a web browser. I recommend phantomjs if you choose that path.